# Is Kendo grid a good option for excel like editing?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am a bit confused about my choice of Kendo UI grid for doing an excel like functionality. 
My requirement is for a lab which they need to log samples and depending on some values do some calculations and update another cell. I need to add new rows to the grid and also do change tracking etc.

Any suggestions on the above?

Comment: If you need a minimum set of formulas it might be acceptable but remember that it is a grid not a spreadsheet so dealing with complex formulas and cells dependencies might be a lot of work.

Comment: Hi OnaBai, thanks for the response.  How do you compare the Kendo grid with the Radgrid in Telerik?

Comment: Never worked with it, no opinion. Sorry!

Comment: In my Kendo grid, I am setting the editmode as "incell" as I need to track the changes at a cell level which is working fine. But when I try to add a row, it messes the grid and every time I fill the cells of the new row, it saves it to the back end. Any inputs on how I can work around with this?

Comment: Yes :) this is because when you save the data into the server you are not returning the `id` of the inserted cells.